# how to trigger jquery to filter by href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi guys so i have two drop-down selects, when a user selects the first it then only shows the options on the second with corresponding values but what i need to do is change the values to a unique value and use the href on the second set of options to link the values heres the js:

```
jQuery.fn.filterOn = function(selectFrom, values) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function() {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);
        console.log(selectFrom);
        $(selectFrom).change(function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
            var haystack = values[$(this).val()];
            console.log(haystack);
            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if($.inArray(option.value, haystack) !== -1) {
                    $(select).append(
                    $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
        });            
    });
};
```

then this is what the selects would look like :

```
<select id="1" name="1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="2" name"2">
<option href="1" value="1">1</option>
<option href="1" value="1">2</option>
<option href="1" value="1">3</option>
<option href="2" value="2">1</option>
<option href="2" value="2">2</option>
<option href="2" value="2">3</option>
</select>
```

what i need to do is to get the second select to sort according to the href instead of the value,
ive tried a few things but all that seems to happen is other jquery starts playing up.

as it currently stands if i select a option with 1 as value on first select it will only show the ones with corresponding value on the second but i need it to show the ones with corresponding href

Comment: Have you looked at any other stackoverflow questions about cascading selects?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select#1').on('change', function() {
  $('select#2 option[href="'+ this.value +'"]').show();
  $('select#2 option[href!="'+ this.value +'"]').hide();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4scmD/4/)**

Or, in a single chain:

```
$('select#1').on('change', function() {
    $('select#2')
          .find('option[href="'+ this.value +'"]') // find options with selected value           
          .show() // show them
          .end()  // backtrack to select#2
          .find('option[href!="'+ this.value +'"]') // find don't match options
          .hide();  // hide unmatched options
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4scmD/3/)**

#### Note

Don't use only numeric `id`s.

Comment: thank you mr paradox i had that code above plus a block of 150+ values just to get it to do the same thing as the 8 lines above